# Flutter : image_picker crash after capturing image from camera and clicking "ok" button in camera preview screen

Tags: flutter, dart

1. package : image_picker
2. Capture image from camera
3. In camera preview page click "OK", app returns to home page
4. Issue found in Poco X3 Android 10 (not working in one specific device of this model)

Tried call back function to check the get the error , but app return to home screen without logging error.
Given camera & media storage permission.

```
 try {
  var _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? pickedFile = await _picker
      .pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
  )
      .then((value) {
    try {
      bloc.emit(ShowToastState(file: value));
    } catch (e) {
      bloc.emit(ShowToastState(msg: e.toString()));
    }
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    bloc.emit(
        ShowToastState(msg: error.toString()));
  });
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    bloc.add(ProfileScreenProfileChangeEvent(
      pickedFile,
      ImageSource.camera,
    ));
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  bloc.emit(ShowToastState(msg: e.toString()));
  handleCameraPermissionError(context, e);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code and error to the question

Comment: try with lower version of image_picker .

Answer (score 0):

#### This crash is probably due to permissions and compatibility issues!

- The crash might occur if there are permission-related issues with the camera or storage permissions. Even though you mentioned that you have granted the necessary permissions, there could be some device-specific differences or restrictions that are causing the crash.
- Certain devices or models might have specific hardware configurations or software implementations that can cause compatibility issues with certain packages or features. So make sure to test on as many devices as possible.
- So this may be you can add a method like `pickImageWithPermission` to ask user camera and storage permission before picking image. It is always a good practice to do so. And **permission_handler** is the perfect plugin for that. This is how it goes.

```dart
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Future<void> pickImageWithPermission() async {
  PermissionStatus cameraPermissionStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
  PermissionStatus storagePermissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
  
  if (cameraPermissionStatus.isGranted && storagePermissionStatus.isGranted) {
    // Permissions are already granted, proceed to pick file
    pickFile();
  } else {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatuses = await [
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    if (permissionStatuses[Permission.camera]!.isGranted &&
        permissionStatuses[Permission.storage]!.isGranted) {
      // Permissions granted, proceed to pick file
      pickFile();
    } else {
      // Permissions denied, handle accordingly (show an error message, request again, or emit your bloc state.)
      // ...
    }
  }
}

Future<void> pickFile() async {
  var picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    // Handle the picked file, emit bloc state
    // ...
  } else {
    // No file was captured, emit bloc error state, or handle as you want
  }
}
```

#### Happy coding

Comment: Tried the above approach already and the same issue occurred. Other flutter apps with image picker has the same issue in this specific device. Tried with other poco X3 device and it worked fine. But instead of image_picker when I tried wechat_camera_picker it works fine. This issue is only happening with image_picker.